# How can I print a simple multiline numeric pattern opposite of how it is emitted now?

Tags: java

This is the output of the following code:

```
1
  23
   345
    4567
```

But I want the output to be in the opposite direction like this.
Not sure how to achieve that.

```
       1
     23
   345
 4567
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numPattern1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= n) {
            int space = n - i + 1;
            while (space <= n) {
                System.out.print(" ");
                space++;
            }
            int j = 1;
            int p = i;
            while (j <= i) {
                System.out.print(p);
                p++;
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hallo, Amar. Please at least try to ask a question instead of simply posting some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each line, there are two spaces times the length of the longest line minus the current line number. Then, you count from the current line number one plus the current line number values. Like,

```
int len = (n / 2) + 1;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * (len - i - 1); j++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
      1
    23
  345
4567
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
public class numPattern1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int i = 1;
```

> int k = 0;

```
    while (i <= n) {
```

> int space = 2*n - i - k ;
>   k++;

```
        int l=0;
```

> ```
>         while (l <= space) {
>             System.out.print(" ");
>             l++;
> ```

```
        }
        int j = 1;
        int p = i;
        while (j <= i) {
            System.out.print(p);
            p++;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
}
```